# Keyboard Malfunction | Certain Keys dont work properly

Tags: laptop, keyboard, sony-vaio

I have a **Sony Vaio Vpcebj1j1e** Laptop .

I have not spilled water or damaged the laptop keyboard.

The problem I encounter is I have certain keys (`W`,`A`,`E`) that don't respond properly.

They work only if I press and hold `D` and press the key I want ,otherwise they don't respond when I tap them.

I checked the keys itself,they are clean and feel no different from others when I press them.

I unplugged the keyboard connector itself and reconnected, the cable is not deteriorated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried updating or reinstalling the driver for the keyboard?  (Bear in mind that you may need an external keyboard to attempt this)

Comment: @CheesusCrust This model does not have any keyboard driver that can be updated. (99% of keyboards don't anyway.)

Comment: I reinstaled from device manager

Answer (score 2):

**1. Drain Power**

I would first try draining any power from the laptop. Take the battery out and press/hold the power button a few times to make sure there is no power left in the laptop itself.

**2. Missing/outdated Driver**

Check the sony website to look for a keyboard driver update for your model of laptop and also try updating it from the device manager under keyboards

**3. Does it work  in BIOS?**

Next check to see if the keyboard is working in BIOS and not OS. If it is try using a Windows 10 repair disk to not only see if your keyboard works there, but attempt to run a repair that could solve the problem.

**4. Turn Off Filter Keys**

Click Start / Settings / Ease of access, then Keyboard in the left pane. Turn off Filter Keys in the right pane and reboot.

**5. External Keyboard**

If nothing else works try an external USB keyboard to see if it fixes your problem. It's a workaround, but will at least let you use your computer more comfortably.

Comment: Used everything so far ,exept filter key which i turned off and on just now but the problem is the same ,i have to press and hold "d" in order be able to pres "w" .

Comment: This problem even occurs when using an external keyboard?

Comment: Sorry i didnt try yet,ill try one this weekend and come with a reply on how it went.

Comment: Do you have any unusual software? Sometimes free antivirus or bloatware can cause weird problems like this. I would also recommend uninstalling and programs you don't use or recognize.

Comment: Used external keyboard works fine this means the problem is with the laptop keyboard.The keys are clean and work fine ,it seams that the signal   sendig might be the problem.I dont understand why keys dont work by themself but work while pressing and holding "D" key.

Comment: Did you determine if it worked in BIOS?

Comment: I tried in bios,It doesnt work